# How to configure Virt-Manager to save snapshots to another server?

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, virt-manager

Hi I have installed KVM and Virt-Manager on three physical computers, and I'm thinking of using a fourth computer to save snapshots or copies of snapshots.

Someone knows how to configure Virt-Manager, so that at the moment of making Snapshots, these are saved in another server (Server 4) and not in local. Or save it locally but make a copy on another server (Server 4).

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The snapshots virt-manager takes are internal (created and managed inside the disk image), and aren't saved to a separate image. If you are looking for a way to back up your VMs, you need to look for backup solutions instead of posing this question

Answer (score 1):

With KVM you have the choice of making internal and external snapshots.
Until now, virt-manager only supports internal snapshots.
If you need external snapshotting, you have to use command line tooling.
A very handy shell script is [this](https://github.com/dguerri/LibVirtKvm-scripts/blob/master/fi-backup.sh).
I've used it for years, with only two crontab entries needed:

10 0 * * * /usr/local/bin/fi-backup.sh -q -v all > /dev/null

0 23 * * sun /usr/local/bin/fi-backup.sh -c -v all > /dev/null

The first entry creates snapshots of all running VM's.
The second entry consolidates all snapshots back into the image once a week.

You need additional scripts to copy the snapshots to your backup location,
and to automatically clean old snapshots from that backup location.